# How to get output linked to input in SPV node?

Tags: transaction-fees, synchronization, spv

We're working on bitcoin SPV wallet. After setting bloom filter, we only get merkle blocks, and transactions that match the hashes we set plus some false positives.

If a transaction is where we **SEND** coins, we can calculate a fee of that transaction, because we also **HAVE** previous transaction holding an output we spent.

But, if a transaction is where we **RECEIVE** coins, then we can't calculate the fee. Because, we **DON'T HAVE** previous transaction holding someone's output which he spent.

As far as I know, there's no way to request single transaction from peers.

How can we get previous transaction or at least it's output's value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get a previous transaction via the p2p network based on the txid.

If you use BIP37, fees for received transactions are difficult to calculate in a decentralised way.

Have a look at BIP158 which will probably be available on the network soon.
It has a [feature](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0158.mediawiki#block-filters) to find the block of your previous txout as well as it doesn't have the privacy problem of BIP37.